# Series of product

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, special-functions

Assuming that you have a series of a product $\sum_{l=0}^{\infty} f(l) g(l)$ and you know what $\sum_{l=0}^{\infty} f(l) $ is. Does this help, finding an approximate form for the whole series?

Comment: What if $g(l)=h(l)/f(l)$? Then your series is anything you want it to be, regardless of what $f(l)$ is.

Comment: Although all of you are saying no, you did not actually pay much attention to the fact, that I am looking for an approximation of this series. so there should be still something left in the approximation that depends on the nature of g, so just saying that this wrong, is not an actual counterexample.

Comment: @Lipschitz. Bien, if you have the product and one series, you could use the Cauchy product rule of polynomial formal series, if this helps..

Comment: actually I do not see how this works, could you post it as an answer and write down what you mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, let $f(l)=1/(l^2)$, then your summation doesn't converge for $g(l)=l$, but it does for $g(l)=1$.

Answer (score 1):

No. For example $f(\ell)=\dfrac{1}{\ell^2}$ and $g(1)=$anything, $g(\ell)=0, \; \forall \; \ell>1$.
 
Then $\sum_{\ell=0}^\infty f(\ell)g(\ell)$ can be anything.